# Cannot resolve column when using inverseJoinColumns

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-security

I am trying to do a many-to-many relationship between my tables using java, but I ran into a problem. The way I designed it so far is *User <-> Roles <-> Privileges* and all of the tables and columns are recognised except for the last *"referencedColumnName = "privilege_id"* in *Role.java* which is not recognised and my IDE does not give any suggestions for this field.
I am not sure if this is the main problem for my project but I do encounter a *throwLazyInitializationException* when a user tries to login.

User.java

```
package com.lukas.ramonas.cms.Model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

/*******************************************
 * Defined user model
 *******************************************/
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_table", schema = "public")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int user_id;

    private String name;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String email;

    private boolean confirmed;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_role_table",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;



/*******************************************
* Setters and getters
*******************************************/

    public Integer getId() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setConfirmed(Boolean confirmed) {
        this.confirmed = confirmed;
    }

    public Boolean getConfirmed() {
        return confirmed;
    }

    public void setRoles(Collection roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Collection<Role> getRoles() { return this.roles;
    }
}
```

Roles.java

```
package com.lukas.ramonas.cms.Model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;

/*******************************************
 * Defined role model
 *******************************************/
@Entity
@Table(name = "role_table", schema = "public")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int role_id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Collection<User> users;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "role_privilege_table",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "privilege_id", referencedColumnName = "privilege_id"))
    private Collection<Privilege> privileges;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public Collection<Privilege> getPrivileges() {
        return this.privileges;
    }
}
```

Privilege.java

```
package com.lukas.ramonas.cms.Model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;

/*******************************************
 * Defined privilege model
 *******************************************/
@Entity
public class Privilege {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int privilege_id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "privileges")
    private Collection<Role> roles;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated and if you need any extra info I would be happy to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the fix to this was really simple.
In my privilege.java class I forgot to add the @Table annotation.
I could fix the problem by adding @Table(name = "privilege_table", schema = "public") to my class as such :

```
package com.lukas.ramonas.cms.Model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;

/*******************************************
 * Defined privilege model
 *******************************************/
@Entity
@Table(name = "privilege_table", schema = "public")
public class Privilege {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int privilege_id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "privileges")
    private Collection<Role> roles;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```